# Flask: How to include html with placeholders in several template files?

Tags: flask

I'm building a web site with flask and have run into the following problem: I have several different pages that use the exact same navigation bar. So far I've just coped and pasted the HTML code that produces the navbar to each of the files but this seems inefficient.

One solution I thought of was to just put {{navbar|safe}} in each of the template files and then store the navbar html in a single file and pass it as an argument to render_template. However, the navbar code also contains placeholders so this doesn't work.

What would be a good approach to accomplishing this?

Answer (score 3):

One of my suggestion is to use {% include "nav.html" %}

Where nav.html contains only your navigation bar.

By using {% include %}, you can place the same navigation bar on different pages.

For example, my master.html might have this set up.

**master.html**

```
{% include "nav.html" %} <!-- your nav html goes here -->

<!-- Section block for item in the page -->
<div class="main">
    <div class = "container">
        {% block section %}

        {% endblock %}
    </div>
</div>
```

For placeholder, {% include %} lets you pass arguments into the nav.html as well.

However, if I understand your placeholder use correctly, it means that your nav relies on arguments. Thus, you need to pass some variables to it.

Let's take a look at a very simple nav.

**nav.html**

```
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="{{link_1}}">{{name_1}}</a></li>
  <li><a href="#"">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

**app.py**

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def landing():
    return render_template('pages/landing_page.html', link_1="somelink", name_1="News")
```

**landing_page.html**

```
{% extends "master_main.html" %}

{% block section %}

    <div class = "content">
       This is my content
    </div>

{%  endblock %}
```

You can see that landing_page.html extends master.html which has nav.html.

Therefore, everypage that you extend master.html will have the same navigation bar.

include lets you pass arguments to nav.html as you can see that I've passed *link_1* and *name_1*

Answer (score 0):

Check explanation of @Niche.P user. I would just like to add my personal project for more practical example.

[Here](https://github.com/PinkFrojd/material_aukcije_online/blob/71f0f61c5f79b0eb50f5d7d79d8070d00ccc7a0e/templates/index.html#L9) you can see I include navbar just like he said from folder partials.

If you check my [templates](https://github.com/PinkFrojd/material_aukcije_online/tree/master/templates) folder, you will see that all the templates include navbar with that one statement, and navbar is in [partials](https://github.com/PinkFrojd/material_aukcije_online/tree/master/templates/partials) folder.